mdapi retrieve doesn't return all FieldUpdate workflow metadata
I need to get metadata files from manually created Workflow Field Update actions.
I created package.xml with following content:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Workflow</name>
    </types>
    <version>61.0</version>
</Package>

then, I tried to retrieve metadata:
dzmitry@debian:/tmp/test-backend/unpackaged$ rm -rf *; sf force:mdapi:retrieve -o test-backend2 --unzip --unpackaged package.xml --retrievetargetdir /tmp/test-backend
 ›   Warning: @salesforce/cli update available from 2.45.6 to 2.53.6.
Warning: We plan to deprecate this command in the future. Try using the "project retrieve start" command instead.
Retrieving v61.0 metadata from test-backend2@velocpq.com.1608-062610 using the v61.0 SOAP API
Retrieve ID: 09SH4000000G4cuMAC
Retrieving metadata from test-backend2@velocpq.com.1608-062610... done
Wrote retrieve zip to /tmp/test-backend/unpackaged.zip
Extracted unpackaged.zip to: /tmp/test-backend/unpackaged
dzmitry@debian:/tmp/test-backend/unpackaged$ find
.
./unpackaged
./unpackaged/package.xml
./unpackaged/workflows
./unpackaged/workflows/Case.workflow
./unpackaged/workflows/Account.workflow
./unpackaged/workflows/Quote.workflow

However, those files is not all FieldUpdate workflows. Tooling soql api returns more of them:
dzmitry@debian:~/work/veloce-integration1$ sf data query -t -o test-backend2 --query 'select Name,Fullname from WorkflowFieldUpdate limit 100'
›   Warning: @salesforce/cli update available from 2.45.6 to 2.54.6.
NAME                               FULLNAME
────────────────────────────────── ────────────────────────────────────────────
Changes the case priority to high. Case.ChangePriorityToHigh
RejectedFieldUpdate                <Company prefix>__ApprovalItem__c.RejectedFieldUpdate
Quote1                             Quote.Quote1
Quote                              Quote.Quote
ApprovedFieldUpdate                <Company prefix>__ApprovalItem__c.ApprovedFieldUpdate
Approval                           <Company prefix>__ApprovalItem__c.Approval
Account                            Account.Account
RecalledFieldUpdate                <Company prefix>__ApprovalItem__c.RecalledFieldUpdate
Case1                              Case.Case1
Total number of records retrieved: 9.
Querying Data... done

As you can see, mdapi retrived Case, Account, Quote workflows, but failed with __ApprovalItem__c related workflows.
Any ideas mdapi doesn't return all metadata?
How to get __ApprovalItem__c metadata files?
UPD:
I also tried package.xml with ApprovalProcess type. The result is approval process with actions, but it only has name and type:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApprovalProcess</name>
    </types>
    <version>61.0</version>
</Package>

Response:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ApprovalProcess xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <active>true</active>
    <allowRecall>true</allowRecall>
    <allowedSubmitters>
        <type>owner</type>
    </allowedSubmitters>
    <approvalPageFields>
        <field>Name</field>
        <field>Owner</field>
    </approvalPageFields>
    <approvalStep>
        <allowDelegate>false</allowDelegate>
        <assignedApprover>
            <approver>
...
            </approver>
            <whenMultipleApprovers>FirstResponse</whenMultipleApprovers>
        </assignedApprover>
        <label>Step1</label>
        <name>Step1</name>
    </approvalStep>
    <enableMobileDeviceAccess>false</enableMobileDeviceAccess>
    <finalApprovalActions>
        <action>
            <name>ApprovedFieldUpdate</name>
            <type>FieldUpdate</type>
        </action>
    </finalApprovalActions>
    <finalApprovalRecordLock>false</finalApprovalRecordLock>
    <finalRejectionActions>
        <action>
            <name>RejectedFieldUpdate</name>
            <type>FieldUpdate</type>
        </action>
    </finalRejectionActions>
    <finalRejectionRecordLock>false</finalRejectionRecordLock>
    <label>ApprovalProcess1</label>
    <processOrder>1</processOrder>
    <recallActions>
        <action>
            <name>RecalledFieldUpdate</name>
            <type>FieldUpdate</type>
        </action>
    </recallActions>
    <recordEditability>AdminOnly</recordEditability>
    <showApprovalHistory>false</showApprovalHistory>
</ApprovalProcess>


Retrieving Workflow retrieves Workflow Rules and their actions. The "missing" actions that you're asking about would be retrieved via ApprovalProcess. When salesforce.com designed Approval Processes, they reused the various Workflow action types, since they serve the same purpose in terms of automation, and they didn't need any additional properties.
